# Show the hovered element for a child element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three buttons for instance. On hover each I calculate the x and y axis of the mouse using jQuery and show a border to the hovered element. For individual elements, the hovering works fine. But for child elements, only the parent element shows border. The code used for the sample.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).mousemove(function(event){
         $(".button").removeClass('active')
      $('.button').each(function(){
        var position = $(this).position();
        var width = $(this).width()
        var height = $(this).height()
        var x1 = position.left 
        var y1 = position.top
        var x2 = x1+width
        var y2 = y1+height
        
        if (event.pageX > x1 && event.pageX < x2 && event.pageY > y1 && event.pageY < y2){
          $("span").text(event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY);
           $(this).addClass('active')
        }
        });

    });
});
```

```css
.button{
  width:150px;
  height:35px;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border:1px solid transparent;
}

.button.x{  top:10%;  left;35%;}
.button.y{top:40%;  left;35%;}
.button.z{top:20%;  left;35%;}
.button.active{
  border-color:blue;
  pointer-events: auto;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button x">
 Hello
 <div class="button y">
 Hello
  </div>
</div>

<div class="button z">
 Hello
</div>

<span></span>
```

Comment: Why would you use jQuery for this?  CSS can do this much easier.

Comment: its because i have too many div's with position: absolute

Comment: @JinsonJohny: What does that matter? CSS's `:hover` doesn't care.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pmcwswt4/ example.. only the outer border hover works

Comment: @JinsonJohny: Because you have that one div on *top* of all the rest. But in any case, if you want to do it with JS, the answer below covers that. :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's a common mistake, due in part to the naming of the jQuery methods involved (IMHO). You're using [`position`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) (*"Get the current coordinates...relative to the **offset parent**."*) where you want to use [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) (*"Get the current coordinates...relative to the **document**."*):

```
var position = $(this).offset();
```

Updated Example (easiest to see if you hit the Full Page link) (I've also added backgrounds to the nested elements and tweaked the border that gets added, to make it clearer when the mouse is over them):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).mousemove(function(event){
         $(".button").removeClass('active')
      $('.button').each(function(){
        var position = $(this).offset();
        var width = $(this).width()
        var height = $(this).height()
        var x1 = position.left 
        var y1 = position.top
        var x2 = x1+width
        var y2 = y1+height
        
        if (event.pageX > x1 && event.pageX < x2 && event.pageY > y1 && event.pageY < y2){
          $("span").text(event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY);
           $(this).addClass('active')
        }
        });

    });
});
```

```css
.button{
  width:150px;
  height:35px;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border:1px solid transparent;
}

.button.x{  top:10%;  left;35%;}
.button.y{top:40%;  left;35%;}
.button.z{top:20%;  left;35%;}
.button.active{
  pointer-events: auto;
  border:2px solid red;
}

.button.x {
  background-color: #00d;
}
.button.y {
  background-color: #0d0;
}
```

```html
<div class="button x">
 Hello
 <div class="button y">
 Hello
  </div>
</div>

<div class="button z">
 Hello
</div>

<span></span>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

---

Or do it with CSS:

```
.button:hover {
  border-color:blue;
  pointer-events: auto;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

(And remove `pointer-events: none;` from `.button`.)

Live Example (with the same visibility tweaks):

```css
.button{
  width:150px;
  height:35px;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  /*pointer-events: none;*/
  border:1px solid transparent;
}

.button.x{  top:10%;  left;35%;}
.button.y{top:40%;  left;35%;}
.button.z{top:20%;  left;35%;}
.button:hover {
  pointer-events: auto;
  border:2px solid red;
}

.button.x {
  background-color: #00d;
}
.button.y {
  background-color: #0d0;
}
```

```html
<div class="button x">
 Hello
 <div class="button y">
 Hello
  </div>
</div>

<div class="button z">
 Hello
</div>

<span></span>
```